# Cocoa app first time open

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mac-app-store

How can I make that dialog box which most of the applications have that when you first open them, it asks you to drag the application into the applications folder? Is there a setting in the project build that I have to specify? How can I do this?

Comment: mac-app-store? apps from the MAS are installed in the application directory by default. And you don't create .dmg files in MAS either. Oh and third, you don't get that view when you open the app for the first time. You get it when you open the .dmg file with Finder.

Comment: No, some apps ask you this the first time they're launched. I personally hate it because I store my apps in `~/Applications` and I hate it when installers/apps assume otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's usable sample code for that at https://github.com/potionfactory/LetsMove/

Comment: +1 That's usable base code, but it's not secure and it can also bork your logging afterwards due to NSTasks that launch shells.